# Ionic 3 validation is not working on "invalid && dirty"

Tags: ionic-framework, angular2-forms

I am trying to implement a validation for inputs in Ionic. For some reason the validation is not firing up. Please see my code below:

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" novalidate>
  <ion-card>

    <ion-card-content>

      <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Email Address</ion-label>
            <ion-input 
            [(ngModel)]="account.email" 
            type="email" 
            name="email" 
            #email="ngModel"
            required
            pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{3,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}([.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}|[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,})"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <div padding *ngIf="email.invalid && email.dirty">
          <span>Email address is not valid.</span>
        </div>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input 
          [(ngModel)]="account.password" 
          type="password" 
          name="password" 
          #password="ngModel"
          required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

    </ion-card-content>

    <ion-row class="login-form__buttons">
      <div>
        <button ion-button (click)="navigateToRegisterPage()" color="secondary">Register</button>
        <button ion-button (click)="login()"  color="primary">Login</button>
      </div>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-card>
</form>
```

The `Email address is not valid.` is not showing. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

With the Ionic version `3.19.1`, when you change something in the html of a component, the changes does not reflect. You have to change something at a `.ts` and save.

Comment: I believe they just patched this bug recently. I was having the same issue and doing research learned there was an open issue on GitHub. I tried it today and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the info.